# ¿Cómo puedo añadir el último valor obtenido?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando capturar todos los `div` que tengo en un formulario, y escoger exactamente el último de ellos.

Hasta ahora tengo esto:

```
<div class="templatecARD" data-group="0" >

        <label>Tarif</label>
        <input type="text" class="name_tarif" name="tarif" onkeyup="formLOGOSTariff.sndFrm()"/>
        
        <div>

            <div class="container-power"></div>
            <button type="button" onclick="formLOGOSTariff.addPower(this.parentNode)">+</button>

        </div>
        <div>

            <div class="container-energy" ></div>
            <button type="button" onclick="formLOGOSTariff.addEnergy(this.parentNode)">+</button>

        </div>

    </div>
```

```
delFrm(){
      var nm = document.getElementsByClassName("templatecARD").length;
      var cont = document.getElementsByClassName("templatecARD")[nm];
      console.log(cont);
   }
```

Con un botón puedo añadir más divs con la misma clase, lo que hago en delFrm() es meter dentro de `nm` el número de divs que hay, y luego intento poner en `cont` el número `nm`, si lo pongo a mano [0] funciona, si lo pongo con el nombre de la variable no.
Necesitaría proporcionar el valor de `nm` dentro de ese array

Answer (score 0):

Vale hecho:

Me di cuenta que `nm` devolvía CUÁNTOS div contaba, por tanto, 1
Y como estaba haciendo las pruebas con 1 div, el div 0 en este caso, me retornaba indefinido.

Ahora tengo esto así:

```
delFrm(){
      var nm = document.getElementsByClassName("templatecARD").length -1;
      var cont = document.getElementsByClassName("templatecARD")[nm];
      cont.remove();
   }
```

Ya que la función original de este botón es eliminar el último div creado.
Muchas gracias a todos.